# C#: What does return top == maxSize - 1 do?

Tags: c#

What is this code doing? Never seen `==` used like this.

```
public bool isFull()
{
    return top == maxSize - 1;
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/equality-operators#equality-operator-

Comment: Same as `top == (maxSize - 1)`

Comment: `==` returns `bool`, so `return top == maxSize - 1;` returns `true` if and only if `top == maxSize - 1`

Comment: `==` is called equality operator, it returns true if its operands are equal , otherwise it returns false

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is this code doing?

It's returning a `bool` value.

> Never seen == used like this.

Sure you have.  For example, what if you saw this?:

```
if (top == maxSize - 1)
```

Is that more familiar?  It's checking a condition to perform an action.  That condition is ultimately a boolean.  Could even be as simple (and pointless) as:

```
if (true)
```

Strip out everything that's around the boolean expression (basically everything that uses the *result* of the expression) and what you have is just that, an expression:

```
top == maxSize - 1
```

Because of [operator precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/#operator-precedence), the different elements of this expression evaluate in a particular order.  So the above is logically equal to:

```
top == (maxSize - 1)
```

So the first thing to happen is to resolve the expression `maxSize - 1`, which resolves to a value.  That value is then compared for equality with `top`, which resolves to `true` or `false`.

This expression resolves to a boolean value, `true` or `false`.  In the code you're showing, the method is simple returning that value.

Answer (score 1):

`==` is an **operator**. It compares the two expressions on either side and produces a **boolean** result.

So when you have `return top == maxSize - 1;`, you are returning the boolean true/false result of the equality expression.

The other clue for this is the signature of the function: `public bool isFull()` is clearly declared as returning a `bool` value.

Answer (score 0):

`==` is called equality operator, it returns true if its operands are equal , otherwise it returns false

so if `top equal (maxSize - 1);` then it returns true, if not equal it returns false

example:

```
public bool IsFull(int a, int b)
{
 //assume a = 2 and b = 3
  return a == b; //result would be false 
}
```